# WEB API. Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Need help.

I have 2 controllers:

```
// POST (Single SMS)
[ActionName("AddSMS")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MySMS singleSMS)
{
    try
    {
        SMS_Repository.Add(singleSMS);
        return Request.CreateResponse<MySMS>(HttpStatusCode.Created, singleSMS);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, "Error");
    }
}

// POST (Collection of SMSes)
[ActionName("AddSMSCollection")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<MySMS> smses)
{
    try
    {
        SMS_Repository.Add(smses);
        return Request.CreateResponse<List<MySMS>>(HttpStatusCode.Created, smses);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, "errorus");
    }
}
```

and Route:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Now. If I send request like this:

**localhost:25856/api/sms/AddSMSCollection**

it works

Is it possible to tune route so that I can use **localhost:25856/api/sms** and didn't get Multiple actions were found that match the request error??

sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 1):

You could define the action that should be executed in this case:

```
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "AddSMS" }
```

But with only the following url `localhost:25856/api/sms` and not including the action name, I hope you realize that the routing engine has no way of disambiguate which action to execute. The routing engine could use the HTTP verb but in your case both actions are POST.

Comment: Darin, your example is not work. When i use localhost:25856/api/sms Fiddler returns 417

Comment: It work if Request body is MySMS singleSMS, but if i sent collection - I get 417